# Search / Filter Dropdown: Change value variable when click

Tags: javascript, html

I just implemented a Search / Filter Dropdown, following this guide: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_filter.

```
<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
        <p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>

        <div class="dropdown">
          <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
          <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
          </div>
        </div>
```

This Search / Filter Dropdown takes the array of the allNameMuseums () method as values, ie ["ACQUARIUM", "Museo2", "Museo3"].

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      allNameMuseums().forEach(function(item) {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").innerHTML += '<a href="' + item + '">' + item + '</a>';
      })
    });


    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    function filterFunction() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
      a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }

    function allNameMuseums() {
      return ["ACQUARIO", "Museo2", "Museo3"];
    }
```

I have two asynchronous methods, specificoMuseo(name) and allMuseums (), and a variable `var data = proof;` that takes the result of the allMuseums() method.

```
specificoMuseo(name).then(proof2 => {
            allMuseums().then(proof => {

var data = proof;

 });
    });
```

I want that when I click on ACQUARIO of Search / Filter Dropdown the variable 'data' takes as input the result of specificoMuseo ("ACQUARIO").

Comment: You meant to say, when drop down item clicked, you need to use that item as parameter of aync "specificoMuseo" function?.

Comment: yes, i need to use item as parameter  "specificoMuseo" function

Comment: Did you tried something <a href="' + item + '" onclick="fnclick(this)">' + item + '</a> **and** function fnclick(obj) {    name = obj.innerHTML } Where **name** is a globle variable.

Comment: can you show me what you say in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to similar logic as below,

```js
var name; //globle variable so you can access in your method 

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function fnclick(obj) {
  name = obj.innerHTML;
  alert(name);
  console.log(name);
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
    border-box: box-sizing;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about" onclick="fnclick(this)">About</a>
    <a href="#base" onclick="fnclick(this)">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog" onclick="fnclick(this)">Blog</a>
  </div>
</div>
```